# ASP.NET CORE, Event to check if the certificate is accepted.

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there an event that we can check after user accepts a SSL certificate in Asp.Net core.

I am working on a project where I need display a message only first time when user accepts certificate and load a relative page after the certificate is accepted.

Comment: huh? How do you expect that to work? ASP.NET Core runs on the server and has no direct user interaction, everything happens via HTTP. The server shouldn't have any idea if user accepts anything or not, as it only happens in the browser. But a successful call to **ANY** of your controller actions implies that the user must have accepted it otherwise he cant establish ssl connections to your actions

Comment: At best you could use a cookie and show the page to users that don't have it.